# Multiple Elements in a Form to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multiple `text boxes` in a form in a HTML page. I want to read the values of the element to an array in the JavaScript. I will set the `name` and `ID` of each element to `name[]` and `ID[]` respectively. How can I read the values of the elements to an `array` in the JavaScript for further operations.

Also, On Update of each element, I want to add the value of the element in the respective positions in the array, ex: the first element in the form in location 0, the second in location 1 ... etc

Comment: Can you please post HTML examples of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't set the id of the element to "ID[]". The id is a NAME token and:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Also, an id *must* be unique. So while you can have multiple elements with the same name, they cannot share an id.

Then, you can get a NodeList (which is almost certainly sufficiently array-like for your purposes) of all the form controls, in a given form, which share a name via:

```
document.forms.id_of_form.elements.name_of_inputs
```

Since the name includes the characters '[' and ']', which have special meaning in JavaScript, you'll have to use square bracket notation instead of dot notation for the last bit.

```
document.forms.id_of_form.elements['name_of_inputs[]']
```

Comment: Umm. You could loop over the NodeList and push ever element on it onto an array. As I said though, the NodeList is almost certainly sufficiently Array-like for you to use it as is.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html).

And heed David Dorward's comments about use of the ID attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example program that does what you want. Hope this helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="frm" id="frm">
   <label>Name1: </label><input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
   <br>
   <label>Name2: </label><input type="text" name="text2" id="text2">
   <br>
   <label>Name3: </label><input type="text" name="text3" id="text3">
   <br>
   <label>Name4: </label><input type="text" name="text4" id="text4">
   <br>
   <label>Name5: </label><input type="text" name="text5" id="text5">
   <br>
   <button id="b1">Click 1</button>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
   if(b1){
    b1.onclick = function(){
     var frm = document.getElementById("frm"),
      vals = [];
     if(frm){
      var textEls = frm.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(var i =0, l = textEls.length; i < l; i++){
       var textEl = textEls[i];
       if(textEl && textEl.type.toLowerCase() === "text" ){
        vals.push(textEl.value);
       }
      }
     }
     alert("Resultant Array: " + vals);
    };
   }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```